# How does g_main_loop_unref(GMainLoop* loop) work?

Tags: glib

**The Question**

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-unref):

```
Decreases the reference count on a GMainLoop object by one. 
If the result is zero, free the loop and free all associated memory.
```

I could not find information regarding this reference counter. What is it initially set to and how is it used?

**Details**

In particular, I'm confused about this piece of example code (in the main method) (note that set_cancel is a static method:

```
void (*old_sigint_handler)(int);

old_sigint_handler = signal (SIGINT, set_cancel);

 /* Create a new glib main loop */
 data.main_loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

 old_sigint_handler = signal (SIGINT, set_cancel);

 /* Run the main loop */
 g_main_loop_run (data.main_loop);

 signal (SIGINT, old_sigint_handler);

 g_main_loop_unref (data.main_loop);
```

If g_main_loop is blocking, how it ever going to stop? I could not find information on this signal method either. But that might be native to the library (although I do not know).

**Note**: I reduced the code above to what I thought was the essential part. It is from a camera interface library called aravis under docs/reference/aravis/html/ArvCamera.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I could not find information regarding this reference counter. What is it initially set to and how is it used?

It is initially set to 1.  Whenever you store a reference to the object you increment the reference counter, and whenever you remove a reference you decrement the reference counter.  It's a form of manual garbage collection.  Just google "reference counting" and you'll get lots of information.

> If g_main_loop is blocking, how it ever going to stop?

Somewhere someone will call [g_main_loop_quit](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-quit).  Judging by the question I'm guessing you're not very familiar with the concept of an event loop—GLib's manual isn't a very gentle introduction to the basic concept, you may want to try the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) or just search for "event loop".

> I could not find information on this signal method either. But that might be native to the library (although I do not know).

The `signal` is a standard function (both C and POSIX).  Again, there is lots of information out there, including good old man pages ([man 2 signal](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)).